# c++ : why I can't assign a value to a non-const static member "inside" a class?

Tags: c++, static

I'm new to C++, and I just can't understand that **why** I can't assign a value to a non-const static member **inside a class** (like we do in java `static int x = 12;` ) even thought I can

- declare a non-const static member (`static int x;`)
- declare a static const member (`static const x;`)
- assign a static const member (`static const int x = 12;`)

*note: my class and my main() function are in the same file*

Comment: What are you trying to do? Static variables in a class do exist.

Comment: Please post code!

Comment: please see [mcve]

Comment: C++ is an evolving language. The rules around this type of code are changing quite quickly. Do you know which *standard* you are targetting? Possibilities include C++98, C++03, C++11, C++14, C++17, and even possibly C++20 (they follow broadly the year of "release").

Comment: C++ is not Java. In fact they are very, very different languages despite some superficial similarities in syntax. If you carry on thinking that C++ will be like Java you are going to have a hard time learning C++.

Answer (score 3):

#### In general

A `static` variable inside a class, just like everything else, is just a *declaration* by default. C++ then requires you to provide a single *definition* per entity that requires one, that's the One Definition Rule. The definition is where the initializer (which is *not* an assignment, but a construction) goes, since there should be only one as well. It is typically placed in a .cpp file so that it can't be accidentally duplicated by `#include`s.

#### The constant case

When a static member is a constant integer or enumeration, and is initialized with a compile-time expression, the initializer is allowed to be placed on the declaration, and the definition skipped. This is a result of a combination of old rules and isn't really interesting today IMO.

#### Proper inline initialization

Since C++17 introduced `inline` variables, you can use them as `static` members. The rules are roughly the same as `inline` functions, and are pretty sensible: you can provide multiple definition of an `inline` entity, you are responsible for ensuring that they are all strictly identical, and the implementation is responsible for collapsing them into a single definition with its initializer. Thus, what you're looking for is written:

```
struct Foo {
    static inline int bar = 42;
    //     ^^^^^^
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise the static member outside the class definition like in this example:

```
class Box {
   public:
      static int x;               
};

// Initialize static member of class Box outside the class definition
int Box::x = 12;

int main(void) {
...
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily in newer C++ standards.